# How to sort content based on values in custom part?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

I created a PersonPart and attached it to my Employee type. It contains a first name and a last name and implements `ITitleAspect` so that when I create a bunch of Employees, they don't all show up as "Employee" in the content list. Now I want to create a Projection that displays all employees ordered by their last name alphabetically.

How can I accomplish this? Is there any interface I can implement to make `FirstName` and `LastName` available as sort criteria?

```cs
public class PersonPart : ContentPart<PersonPartRecord>, ITitleAspect
{
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("First name")]
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return Retrieve(r => r.FirstName); }
        set { Store(r => r.FirstName, value); }
    }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Last name")]
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return Retrieve(r => r.LastName); }
        set { Store(r => r.LastName, value); }
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get { return LastName + " " + FirstName; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add your new bindings from 'Bindings' tab under 'Queries' menu.

Comment: @mdameer That's what I needed. Seems obvious but it's easy to overlook. Couldn't find anyone pointing out this simple fact after 20 minutes of googling so I think it would be useful to have it here as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add new bindings in Orchard to use in custom queries, you have to add these bindings as following:

1. You should go to `Bindings` page as following:

[image: Bindings]

then press on `Add a New Binding` button.

2. In `Add a Binding` page, you will see all your records properties (it will not include your `ContentPart` properties if it's does not has a `ContentPartRecord`), which you can add new binding for them:

[image: Add a Binding]

Here, you can select the property you want to add binding for.

3. Then, You are free to enter the `Display` text and `Description` for your property binding:

[image: Binding]

4. Now, if you go to your query edit page, and try to add a new filter for it, you will see the new binding there (notice that the display name you entered in the previous step is very important here to describe your binding to be very clear for others):

[image: Add a Filter]

5. Finally, you will see the newly created binding in your `Edit Query` page:

[image: Edit Query]